# Can't get framerate agnostic acceleration in processing sketch

Tags: java, processing

I have a sketch where I simulate gravity like this:

```
float acceleration;
float velocity;
float location; 

int time= millis();

boolean done = false;
void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  acceleration = 0;
  velocity = 0;
  location = 0;
  frameRate(30);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  acceleration = acceleration + .1;
  gravity();
  ellipse(10, location, 10, 10);

  if (location > height && !done) {
    float finished = millis() - time;
    println(finished/1000.0);
    done = true;
  }
}

void gravity() {
  velocity += acceleration * (1/frameRate);
  location += velocity;
  acceleration = 0;
}
```

I would have figured I could simply multiply acceleration by 1/frameRate to make the simulation run the same regardless of framerate, but it doesn't work. How can I simulate gravity or forces independent of framerate?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that multiplies `acceleration` by `1/frameRate`? Also why do you need to do this?

Comment: I edited it to add it in. I'm following this video by Shiffman where he talks about adding a force. However this method makes things move at different speeds depending on the framerate. I want it to take the same number of ms to reach the bottom regardless if it is 10fps or 100fps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkXoQVWRDJs

Comment: But why is your program going to be running at different framerates? Your life will be so much easier if you just stick with the default.

Comment: because I want to calibrate it for real world scale/time, and the framerate isn't steady enough to get accurate results especially in game when it often dips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the current speed a function of time, not of the number
of frames painted.  something like

```
long start = <now>;
position = 0;
do { position = functionof(<now>-start); repaint(); sleep(10); }
```

then the actual repaint, whenever it occurs, uses the current position.